# C# MVC Adding the DB2 to data source list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, db2

I tried to follow some instruction from online reference but somehow the DB2 data source is not appearing for the setting up of connection string:

I already done:

- install the IBM.DB2 from manage nuget packages
- download Latest DsDriver Package from this [page](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/download.do) .

[image]

Comment: your posted link is invalid. the IBM Data Server Client Packages can be downloaded from here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878

Comment: Maybe also, post the link to the "some instruction from online reference" that you followed

Comment: Your screenshot shows "Data Provider for SQL Server"; Db2 data source types would probably show when the appropriate provider is selected.